# AVC denied ... Kotlin android studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, permissions, logcat

recently, I've been facing this message in my android studio Logcat :

> avc: denied { read } for name="perf_ioctl" dev="proc" ino=4026533700
>   scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:proc:s0
>   tclass=file permissive=0

I don't know what it is and if this will cause some issue in the future. It happens litteraly for anything I'm doing on my app (click on menu, swipe...)

What is this ?

Comment: No issue at all.

Comment: So what is this ? Why do I have that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [SELinux](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux) denial. You can ignore it as it won't affect your app. There isn't anything you can do about it (at a user level).

If you are using a custom ROM, the maintainer needs to update his sepolicy.

Comment: Ok, I thought this was the reason of my errors. Ok, thanks !

Comment: Please accept it as an answer if it resolved your query